how to define an interface with generic type
For example, how can I define a TestType that extends BaseType, and also accept a generic type.
If my code is like below:
type BaseType={
  id:number
}
interface TestType<T=any> extends BaseType {
  prop1:string;
  [key: string]: T;
}

I get some ts-error TS2411 like this:
Property 'prop1' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'T'.

How can I solve it?

The problem is that [key: string] means key can be prop1 or id as well which will most likely result in a conflict with the already existing types. Something like this would work but harder to use

What is your intent here? If I wrote TestType<boolean>, would you expect that to be "an interface with a numeric id, a string prop, and a bunch of other properties all of which are boolean"? If so, that's not directly possible in TS and this question is effectively a duplicate of this one. If not, please [edit] to demonstrate what you expect to do with such a type.

You need to make sure that the index signature [key: string]: T does not conflict with the explicitly defined properties.
type BaseType = {
  id: number;
};

interface TestType<T = any> extends BaseType {
  prop1: string;
  [key: string]: T | string | number;  // compatibility with prop1 and id
}


This is a simple alternative but it does mean you can end up with properties that are not id or prop1 that are also not of type T

@apokryfos You are correct, and I can't think of a way to restrict that.

if my code is like this
  prop1:'1',
  more:{moreId:1,name:'ad'},
}```
it will say ``Type '{ moreId: number; name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string | number | { more: { moreId: number; name: string; }; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'moreId' does not exist in type '{ more: { moreId: number; name: string; }; }'. Did you mean to write 'more'?ts(2322)``

@KentWood Of course, the proper way to define aa would be var aa: TestType<{moreId: number, name: string}> = { id: 1, prop1: '1', more: { moreId: 1, name: 'ad' } }; You define the type of more, not define the type of an object containing more.

nop, the structure what i need is { id: 1, prop1: '1', more: { moreId: 1, name: 'ad' } }, the more property is extends from generic type define.
